# IOS - testing app on real device is looking different than in the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, testing

When i run my app on my Iphone it is zoomed and images in the images.xcassets doesn't load and become a X here is some screen shot:

**In the simulator:**

[image: In the simulator]

**On my Iphone:**

[image: On my iphone]

And as you can see the fps is lower on my Iphone

I am loading the images using:

```
let stick = SKSpriteNode(ImageNamed: "stick")
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this

Comment: There are a lot of different places that could be causing this issue. Can you post your image loading logic? Can you verify that the images are actually being copied to the device? What have you already tried for debugging the image loading? As for the fps, that's likely a whole separate issue that should be handled on its own.

Comment: I've added how i load the images and how do i copy the images to the device i thought it was doing it automatically and why is it zooming?